# Getting random lines from Trove (TObjectIntHashMap)?

Tags: java, random, hashmap, benchmarking, trove4j

Is there a way to get random lines from a Trove (TObjectIntHashMap)? I'm using Random to test how fast a Trove can seek/load 10,000 lines. Specifically, I'd like to pass in a random integer and have the Trove seek/load that line. I've tried using the get() method, but it requires that I pass a string rather than a random int. I've also considered using keys() to return an array and reading from that array, but that would defeat the purpose as I wouldn't be reading directly from the Trove. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import com.comScore.TokenizerTests.Methods.TokenizerUtilities;

import gnu.trove.TObjectIntHashMap;

public class Trove {

    public static TObjectIntHashMap<String> lines = new TObjectIntHashMap<String>();

    public static void TroveMethod(List<String> fileInArrayList)
            throws IOException {
        TObjectIntHashMap<String> lines = readToTrove(fileInArrayList);
        TokenizerUtilities.writeOutTrove(lines);
    }

    public static TObjectIntHashMap<String> readToTrove(
            List<String> fileInArrayList) {

        int lineCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < fileInArrayList.size(); i++) {

            lines.adjustOrPutValue(fileInArrayList.get(i), 1, 1);
            lineCount++;
        }

        TokenizerUtilities.setUrlInput(lineCount);
        return lines;
    }

    public static void loadRandomMapEntries() {
        Random rnd = new Random(lines.size());

        int loadCount = 10000;

        for (int i = 0; i < loadCount; i++) {
            lines.get(rnd);
        }

        TokenizerUtilities.setLoadCount(loadCount);
    }
}
```

The method in question is loadRandomMapEntries(), specifically the for-loop. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would:

1. Create an array of the values you want to insert.
2. Loop through the array and insert those keys.
3. Pick a random index from the array and do the lookup for that key.

There are [benchmarks that come bundled with Trove](https://bitbucket.org/trove4j/trove/src/e358042a4703e9f222ea282d821861293452ecc7/benchmarks/src/gnu/trove/benchmark/GetBenchmark.java?at=master) that essentially do that already, so you could take a look at those.

Keep in mind that benchmarking is tricky to get right. I'd recommend that you use a framework like [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for your benchmarking and be sure to always test in your application to see real-world performance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've done steps 1 and 2, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to lookup the key by using the value. I stumbled on your other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120131/tintobjecthashmap-get-key-for-given-value). However, when doing that same exact code, I get another error under forEachEntry: 

"The method forEachEntry(TObjectIntProcedure<String>) in the type TObjectIntHashMap<String> is not applicable for the arguments (new TIntObjectProcedure<String>(){})"

Do you know why this could be? Thanks again, Rob!

Comment: Glad to help!

Your "Object" and "Int" are reversed in your question. I'm not sure if that's a typo or the real problem. [Here's code](http://pastebin.com/pYQnbkkE) that does the key lookups. Hope it helps!